# How the segmentation falut can be solved?

Tags: c, malloc

i got a segmentation fault error while calling this function

```
pterm *readterm()
{
    pterm *node;
    int exp;
    int coeff;
    printf("\nEnter exponent:");
    scanf("%d",&exp);
    printf("\nEnter exponent:");
    scanf("%d",&coeff);
    node=getnode();
    node->prev=NULL;
    node->exp=exp;
    node->coeff=coeff;
    node->next=NULL;
    return node;
}
```

[the output i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exKxb.png)

Comment: Something is probably wrong with `getnode()`, whose code you didn't show us, causing it to return a null or invalid pointer.  Please create a [mcve].

Comment: You cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return***. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 2):

Segmentation fault is a specific kind of error caused by accessing memory that “does not belong to you." That means if you want to use pointer `pterm *node` for this code, you should take space for the pointer from memory.

As far as I see problem would be on function of `getnode()` because if it was correct there would not be any problem about memory.

Comment: You can format code inline by placing one `\`` (backtick) around it. I'll fix it here.